# Generated files on host from docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have setup my node project with docker.
I generate xml files in my project.
I have mounted a drive on my host.
So whenever my project generate xml from docker, i want it to be moved to the mounted drives on my host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mount the folder where your XML files are generated inside your container to a folder in your host computer. Doing this, content of both directories will be always the same.

To do this, you have to use flag `-v` in `docker run` command.

`docker run ... -v /path/to/host/directory:/path/to/container/directory ...`